# Rotation in selected item in Spinner control

Tags: java, android, spinner, arabic

I have problem in selected item in spinner android control.In Arabic language  Selected item text reversed and go to arrow side.I tried to rotate the view of selected item ( view.setRotationY(180) ) but it rotated on other android versions.
What is the best solution to solvie this issue?

[image: Wrong spinner potion]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

rotate will effect on the rotation of the view
you must change the gravity of your xml layout
force direction to be ltr  or your text layout direction

```
android:layoutDirection="ltr"
android:textDirection="ltr"
```